# Formsite.com not mapping the desired record type ID

Tags: record-type

I am building 4 online submission forms that will create Orders__c in my org. This is my first exposure to creating new forms in Formsite, although I've had to adjust some in the past. I followed my predecessor's methods to pass the recordtypeID through a hidden field and cannot come to conclusion as to why it will not append properly in Salesforce.

- I have full admin permissions in the org
- The forms are linked through
  a different admin's sfdc account though he has a full admin account
  as well

In the picture:

1. The mapping in Formsite's SF integration that displays that my
   hidden field is correctly mapped to `** Record Type ID`
2. The default
   value of the hidden field is correctly set to the desired record
   type ID
3. The URL and ID of from the record type edit page

The order is submitted as it should but it is submitted using the wrong record type (used for numerous other forms via Formsite) `012A0000000zdrY`whereas desired: `012A00000012jVQ`. Does anyone have experience with this issue or know of other possible avenues for investigating?

edit: I have tried both 15- and 18- character record type Ids

[image]

Comment: you telling that you need 4 online submission forms. Do you want 1 form for each recordtype ?

Comment: That's correct @IlyaLepesh but I think I got it figured out, adding answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may have just been an artifact from the way I cloned and subsequently edited the forms but I've managed to solve the issue.

All I did was delete the hidden field and recreate it. The only actual change that occurred was the name of the field from `recordtypeid` to `Record Type ID`. The passed value was copied from the deleted field to the new one, so while I did not learn what the root cause was, the issue has been solved.